# Luarocks Failed to Compile Object

Tags: lua, luarocks, moonscript

I'm pretty new to using things like luarocks to install libraries, and I'm running into a problem I'm not sure how to fix when installing the dependencies for Lapis.

[image]

As you can see, I have none of the dependencies installed for Lapis (I assume that they'll automatically install when I attempt to download Lapis). I'm using the regular command prompt for this. Being so new, I imagine I could be doing many things wrong. Should I be using something else? Any pointers would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Getting this message:

```
'cl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

means that you don't have a C compiler in your executables search path (`PATH` environment variable). In particular, LuaRocks is searching from `cl`, which is the C compiler from Microsoft Visual Studio. If you have Visual Studio installed, you should launch its "x86 Development Command Prompt", and then the directory where `cl.exe` is will be set in your `PATH` and LuaRocks will find it.

Using Visual Studio is the default configuration for LuaRocks on Windows, but you can also using with [MingW](http://mingw.org). The easiest way to set this up is to use `INSTALL /MW` when installing LuaRocks.

In any case, I'm not sure if Lapis is compatible with Windows — you should check that in its documentation!

Comment: After adding the location of cl.exe to my path I get "src/mime.c(5): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'string.h': No such file or directory" ;-;

Comment: You should not edit `PATH` directly, you should use the batch script provided by Microsoft, as it sets other necessary environment variables.