# How to use lua web sockets on windows?

Tags: windows, sockets, lua, luarocks

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17150645/2136963) answer suggests [this](https://github.com/lipp/lua-websockets) library to use web sockets for lua.

The installation guide of the library contains three strings:

> $ git clone git://github.com/lipp/lua-websockets.git
>
> $ cd lua-websockets
>
> $ luarocks make rockspecs/lua-websockets-scm-1.rockspec

I don't know what results of the last command should be and how to proceed from executing it to compiling examples. But on my PC it only produces error message

> '"C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\\lua5.1.exe"' is not recognized as
> internal or external command, operable program or batch file

in visual studio 2015 developer console.

In regular console it just complains that [cl is not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28922447/2136963)

I want to know not only ways of fixing the error, but all actions needed to start communicating with websockets from a lua  script on windows with this library or another one.

The script will be run in vm provided by a third party app. I can `require` external modules from it. I installed luarocks from developer console. There are no other installed lua frameworks/compilers. The system is windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to run this as the client, then you only need three pieces: lua interpreter, luasocket library, and the lua-websockets module you referenced. The module has other dependencies (luabitop and copas), but those are optional if you just want to try simple sync calls using luasocket. You can compile luasocket libraries yourself (that's what luarocks probably attempted for you to do, but you can also do it from the command line) or find already compiled libraries; for example, see [this discussion](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2013-05/msg00457.html) for details.

Comment: Is lua-ev optional? Because it seems, that it cannot be used on windows at all.

Comment: I think it's optional when other servers/clients are used (copas or sync).